# variable event referenced before assignment although I referenced it

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to put all my game levels inside one program. Before that all codes worked perfectly. However when I put all programs inside their functions and tried to run first level I got an error:

```
 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP and igralec.y > 10:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
```

I searched this error online and did what fix is supposed to be; I put those lines of code under for event loop, but that made the game unplayable; I had to press key for just one move (holding it didn't work). Then I tried to change if to while, which didn't work either. Here' s the code:

```
 while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and igralec.ziv > 0:
                print(igralec.fire_rate)
                igralec.fire_rate += 1
                if igralec.fire_rate == 4:
                    igralec.fire_rate = 1 
                if igralec.fire_rate % 2 == 1 or igralec.fire_rate == 1:
                    strel.play()   
                    if igralec.levo:
                        smer = -1
                    else:
                        smer = 1
                    if len(metki) < 5:
                        metki.append(torpedo(igralec.x, igralec.y + 40, smer))
    for metek in metki:
        if metek.x < 1024 and metek.x > 0:
            metek.x +=  metek.v
            if metek.x > podmornca.okvir[0] and metek.x < podmornca.okvir[0] + podmornca.okvir[2]:
                if metek.y > podmornca.okvir[1] and metek.y < podmornca.okvir[1] + podmornca.okvir[3]:
                    zadetek.play()
        else:
            metki.pop(metki.index(metek))
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP and igralec.y > 10:
        igralec.y -= 5
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and igralec.y < 600:
        igralec.y += 5
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        igralec.levo = True
        igralec.desno = False
        eksploziv.x += igralec.v
        kamenx += igralec.v
        podmornca.zac += igralec.v
        podmornca.konc += igralec.v
        podmornca.x += igralec.v
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        igralec.levo = False
        igralec.desno = True
        eksploziv.x -= igralec.v
        kamenx -= igralec.v
        podmornca.zac -= igralec.v
        podmornca.konc -= igralec.v
        podmornca.x -= igralec.v
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT :
        if igralec.ziv < 0: 
            restart = True
```

Comment: It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The event handling  `if event.type == ...` has to be done **in** the event loop rather than **after** the event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @pjk and others, you do need the code for checking the keys to be in the event loop.

You said when you fixed that the game became unplayable since you had to repeatedly hit the keys because *holding the key down did nothing*. The key being pressed down is an event and it only happens when the key is pressed down. You also get an event when a key is released but no events are generated as it is being held down. However there are ways around this.

**Here are some ways to fix that:**

I like the repeating key approach, which is why I will cover it first.

You can tell pygame that you want it to repeat giving you key down events if the key is held down. This is similar to what many systems do whan a key is held down. You can get it by telling pygame that you want it to periodically give you KEYDOWN events while the key is held down. You use the command `pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval)` (docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_repeat)). Basically pygame will fake KEYDOWN events for you when a key is held down. The `delay` is how long a key needs to be held down before the first repeat key event is sent, and the `interval` is how often you want the event repeated after the initial delay.

You can also do it another way. Instead of reacting to keys when they are pressed, you track the state of keys that you want to have the game react to. When you get a `KEYDOWN` event for one of those keys you set a state variable indicating that key has been pressed. You clear that variable when you get the corresponding `KEYUP` event for that key. Then outside the event loop you can react to those key state variable to make things happen as long as the keys are held and the state is set.

There is a further way, where you ask pygame what keys are currently pressed using `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. You then parse the currently pressed keys out of the return. See docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed).

If you use `get_pressed()` you still need an event loop to process events or pygame will not process events and you game will go unresponsive. You can also use `pygame.event.pump()` to prevent this stalling.

Comment: @JonatanJurkovnik Great! Out of curiosity, which way did you do it?

Comment: I used pygame.key.get_pressed(). It seemed weird that way I used didn't work when I changed program to function.

Answer (score 0):

`event` is local to the first for loop. and after the loop ends `event` will be out of scope.
 `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP and igralec.y > 10: igralec.y -= 5` is outside the for loop which is the reason for this error.

Comment: Loops do not have separate scope. The loop iterable is likely just empty., thereby never binding anything to `event` in the first place. (The fix is the same, though.)

Comment: if the loop ends, the the loop variable would hold only last value.  and if `pygame.event.get()` is `None` or `[]` then `event` never is declared hence throws error  "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment"

Comment: May be the use of "out of scope" was the reason for confusion

Comment: I tried to put inside for loop, but when I do that the game becomes unplayable; holding key doesn't do anything.